# GPS-Plugin and Garmin data

Tags: qgis, import, gpx, garmin

I am an avalanche specialist and I use a GPS Garmin 62 for fieldwork.
I for example use waypoints to measure snow depth in avalanches for volume calculations.

When I add a waypoint in the garmin unit it allows me to enter digits in the predefined field called depth. This field depth can be seen in the attribute table for GPX in Garmin Basecamp.
However the QGIS does not import this field, for it only imports standard GPS data.

Does anybody have a solution on how to import this field into Quantum GIS?

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on HasT's answer, use GPSBabel to translate the GPX file to another format; I prefer to use CSV which appears as "Universal csv with field structure in first line" in GPSBabel's format dropdown.

Then in QGIS make sure you have the Add Delimited Text Layer plugin enabled and use it to add your new csv file to your map.

Answer (score 1):

Try the programm GPSBabel (http://www.gpsbabel.org/).

Comment: I didnt get this running properly until I got instructions from HeyOverThere. But thanks